# Possible to use SQLite plugin with Ionic React on the browser platform?

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, plugins, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to use SQLite ([SQLite - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite)) in my Ionic React WebApp when it is running in the browser?
SQLite is a Cordova plugin but it can be used in a React app as well: React apps use Capacitor to build native mobile apps. However, Ionic Native (and therefore, Cordova plugins) can be used ([React - Ionic Native Community - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community#react)).
The official documentation of the plugin says that the browser platform is now supported ([GitHub - storesafe/cordova-sqlite-storage: ...](https://github.com/storesafe/cordova-sqlite-storage#alternative-browser-platform-usage-notes)), but it doesn't specifically refer to Ionic or React.

I don't understand how to make the SQLite plugin work with React in the browser?

This code doesn't throw any errors and from what I've read it would work on an Android or iOS phone:

```
import { IonAlert, IonButton, IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ExploreContainer from '../components/ExploreContainer';
import './Home.css';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite'


const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
  const initDb = (): void => {
    SQLite.create({
      name: 'data.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

        db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', [])
          .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));

      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Blank</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <IonButton onClick={initDb}>Init DB</IonButton>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

In the browser (ionic serve) I receive this error message followed by dozens of yellow errors:

TypeError: can't access property "then", *ionic_native_sqlite__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5*_.SQLite.create(...) is undefined
initDb
C:/Users/UserAccount/Documents/Ionic-Projekte/Test-1-SQLite-Blank/src/pages/Home.tsx:12

```
   9 | const Home: React.FC = () => {
  10 |   const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
  11 |   const initDb = (): void => {
> 12 |     SQLite.create({
  13 |       name: 'data.db',
  14 |       location: 'default'
  15 |     })
```